# Domain Expired issues

Tags: domains, domain-registration, google-workspace

We are facing a problem regarding the renewal of a Google Apps domain. Our domain is `badrealam.com` and it expired on 2014-02-07 as we mistakenly did not renew it.

Now we are trying to renew it but unfortunately it's not working, however it shows 30$ in my balance as they want 10$ to renew it.

Someone told me that you have to renew your hosting also which is on GoDaddy.

Comment: Could you be more specific with "unfortunately its not working"? Is  renewal process not working or did you renew successfully but the site is still down?

Comment: [Please use ISO 8601 formatted dates.](https://xkcd.com/1179/) I thought you were claiming your domain had expired on a date in the future (or that I missed a year).

Answer (score 4):

From [GoDaddy's support page](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6700/what-happens-after-domain-names-expire):

> What happens after domain names expire?
>
> Once a domain name expires, it goes through many stages before being released to the open market. Go Daddy sends five renewal emails to the domain name's administrative contact prior to the expiration date. Below is a timeline based on .com domain names.
>
> **Day 1** We make the first of three billing attempts to renew the domain name. If the billing fails, the domain name expires. The domain name can be renewed by the registrant at no extra cost.
>
> **Day 5** We make the second billing attempt. If the billing fails again, the domain name is parked. The domain name can still be renewed by the registrant at no extra cost.
>
> **Day 12**    We make the third and final attempt to renew the domain name. The domain name can still be renewable by the registrant at no extra cost.
>
> **Day 19**    The domain name can be renewed by the registrant for the cost of a one-year renewal plus an $80.00 redemption fee.
>
> **Day 26**    We add the domain name to an expired domain name auction.
>
> **Day 36**    The expired domain name auction ends. If there are no backorders and no bidders in the expired domain name auction, we list the domain name in a closeout auction.
>
> **Day 41**    The closeout auction ends.
>
> **Day 43**    We assign the domain name to the winner of the expired domain name auction, backorder, or closeout. If there are no bidders, we return the domain name to the registry.

You appear to be on day 45(!?), so providing no-one else has already registered it, you should be able to **re-register** it again. (Not a standard "*renewal*".)